# How do I use a variable to identify another variable in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to basically do this:

```
string x = "hi";
int hi = 3;
Console.WriteLine([x].ToString());
```

get what I'm trying to do? I want to print "3", not "hi." I want to use x to reference to hi. how might I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds like you should use a `Dictionary<string,int>`.

Comment: You could use reflection for that. Granted, not for local variables (correct me if I'm wrong?).

Comment: Consider move away from PHP and learn real programming techniques, read Matts comment and rcravens answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try (sorry i'm typing from my phone)

```
class MyClass
{

  public int x {get;set;}
  MyClass()
  {
      x = 3;
  }

  void Foo()
  {
      Type type = GetType();
      PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty("x");

      object xValue= pInfo.GetValue(this, null);
      Console.Writeln(xValue); 
  }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data["hi"] = 3;

Console.WriteLine(data["hi"]); // prints 3
```

Comment: Should int and string be reversed in your example to accomplish what he wants?  Or am I just being dense?